# shell script - creating folder structure

Tags: macos, bash, shell, console

I wrote this little shell script(test.sh) to create a basic folder structure:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if directory already exists,
# if it doesnt, create one.
if [ ! -d "~/.dir1" ]; then
        mkdir ".dir1"
else
        rm -rf ".dir1"
        mkdir ".dir1"
fi
```

When I run

```
test.sh
```

in console, the hidden folder is created.

But:
When I run it again it tells me:

```
mkdir: .dir1: File exists
```

But it could exist because I removed it in my shell script before I created a new one!
So why does it display this message?

Thanks and greetings!

Comment: Consider setting up [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) in your editor to automatically have issues like this pointed out.

Comment: You should consider not using a two way process for this, after you check for if directory exist with `if`, another thread/process can create it before the mkdir inside if is reached, In that case you will get the same error again. @hek2mgl s answer is the way to go for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
[ ! -d "~/.dir1" ]
```

by

```
[ ! -d "${HOME}/.dir1" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use `-p`.

```
mkdir -p "$HOME/dir1"
```

If you pass `-p`, `mkdir` wouldn't throw an error if the directory already exists, it would simply silently return in that case.

If you want to make sure folder is empty use this:

```
rm -rf "$HOME/dir1"
mkdir -p "$HOME/dir1"
```

and **no** if! The basic problem with the `if` is the fact that it is not immune against race conditions. When the script went off from CPU right after the `if` - and creates "dir1" - your script will fail when it enters the CPU again since it still thinks the directory does not exist.

Comment: But the OP is removing the directory before running `mkdir`

Comment: A race condition isn't happening here, though if you use `mkdir -p`, the if statement isn't needed any more. What I tried to say is that the OP is removing the directory before creating it, so there isn't any problem with mkdir, the problem is elsewhere (in the if condition). basically from second run the `mkdir` inside `if` is being called

Comment: @Jahid I just mentioned that a race condition *can* happen if you are using an `if` block, making the `if` block worthless at all. (Even if seen too much in shell scripts (and in the accepted answer)). About the `rm -rf`, Note that this command will remove the folder *and* it's contents, if we just use `mkdir -p` it is not safe that the folder will be empty, meaning it would not being the same as the attempt shown in the question.

Comment: Thank you! :) Just a good advice: If you see something like `if(!file_exists('foo')) { touch("foo"); }` the first thing you should have in mind should be "race condition!".. Unfortunately too many people don't care about that.

Comment: yap, the file can be created by another thread/program in-between condition check and `touch `

Comment: yes, that's why simply `touch('foo');` is enough + simplifies the code. It is seldom in programming that doing less brings more! :D hehe

Comment: Your answer should be the accepted one, creating directory after exists check with `if` is really not the way to go about it...

Comment: It's like parsing HTML with regexes, you'll see questions related to that popping up every day :) I also wonder why they even implemented the `-d` or `-f` check in `test`... Will search for some answers in the mailing lists.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing by `"~/.dir1"` is not right. It's just another string for a directory name literally `"~/.dir1"` i.e `~` is not being expanded to `$HOME`.

Use  full path or `~/".dir1"` or `~/.dir1` instead.

You can use `$HOME` too: `$HOME/.dir1` or `"$HOME/.dir1"` or `"$HOME"/".dir1"` all of them will produce same result... but quoting variables is a good practice.

Comment: Or even better, use `"$HOME/.dir1"` for portability.

Answer (score 1):

`~` isn't expanded when you place it in quotes. You need to leave it unquoted.

```
if [ ! -d ~/.dir1 ]
```

Of note, you're checking for `~/.dir1` but you make `.dir1`. That's only the same directory if the current directory is `~`. If it isn't, they're not the same.

Also, `mkdir -p` will do this for you, creating a directory only if it doesn't exist already. You could simplify your script to:

```
mkdir -p ~/.dir1
```

or

```
rm -rf ~/.dir1
mkdir ~/.dir1
```

Comment: About the second example: When the script leaves the CPU right after `rm -rf ~/.dir` and another process creates the dir, then `mkdir ~dir` will fail without `-p`. I know I am pedantic! :P